# dilatation analytic

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

I have seen that the spectrum of the operator  $T=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2$ is the $\{2n+1,n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ and by dilatation $x=r y$ the spectrum of the operator $T_r=-r^{-2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+r^2x^2$ is the set $\{(2n+1)r^2,n \in \Bbb{N}\}$. Why we have that.
Thanks